# Python and MySQL connection

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.7, mysql-8.0

I know how to connect the python script and MySQL database, but when the DB isn't running i can't do it, so i need to run my DB at first.
The main question is how to run my database from python script? Usually i'm running it from MySQL Workbench, but i want it to run for example with **init** method of my GUI's class.
I'm using mysql.connector module for connectivity.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "12121212",
    database = 'mydb',
    auth_plugin = "mysql_native_password"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from tab")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

Comment: How is your code relevant to your question? To launch an external command from Python, use https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL server can be runned in this way:

```
import os

os.chdir("C:/")
os.system("net start mysql80") #running service mysql[version] (my version is 8.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, i hope it is what you need!

```
https://codetheory.in/how-to-write-a-python-script-which-communicates-with-the-mysql-server/
```

Comment: Not really, i have no problems with connection to the running MySQL server, but i want to know how to run this server from python script.

Comment: You could run the sql server using the os module